# formulario html/php

Tags: php, javascript, html

Boas pessoal , estou a fazer um formulario só que está me acontecer um pequeno imprevisto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em alguns campos não aparece a informação completa e não sei porque. Por exemplo, o nome em vez de estar Diogo Faria por exemplo apenas aparece Diogo e o mesmo se verifica noutros campos mais à frente do formulário.

Pensei que pudesse ser do tamanho dos `inputs` porém já tentei aumentar e continua igual.
A informação recebida através de um pedido `ajax` e já verifiquei e recebe a informação toda, o que esta mal é mesmo ao inserir essa informação no formulário

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajaxUtentes.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bi:bi},
      success: function(dados){

          alert(dados.Nome);

        var strVar="";
strVar += "<form>   ";
strVar += "        <table>";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Dados de idenificação do utente<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"nome\">Nome<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"nome\" name=\"nome\" value="+dados.Nome+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
```

Isto é um excerto do código que recebe a informação e insere no formulário.

Parte de `javascript` com o `html`:

```
function Utentes(bi)
{
    alert(bi);
    if (bi=="")
    {
        $('#contas').html("Nao existe ninguem com esse BI");

        return;
    }
    //$('#contas').html('<img alt="ajax_loader" src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "ajaxUtentes.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {bi:bi},
      success: function(dados){

          alert(dados.Nome);
          if(dados.Nome==null){
              alert("Não existe ninguem com esse BI")
          }
          else{
        var strVar="";
strVar += "<form>   ";
strVar += "        <table>";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Dados de idenificação do utente<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"nome\">Nome<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"nome\" name=\"nome\" value="+dados.Nome+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"idade\">Idade<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"idade\" name=\"idade\" value="+dados.idade+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"dataNascimento\">Data Nascimento:<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"date\" id=\"dataNascimento\" name=\"dataNascimento\" value="+dados.dataNascimento+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"estadoCivil\">Estado Civil<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"estadoCivil\" id=\"estadoCivil\" value="+dados.estadoCivil+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>   ";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                ";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"nacionalidade\">Nacionalidade<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" id=\"nacionalidade\" name=\"nacionalidade\" value="+dados.nacionalidade+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <label for=\"naturalidade\">Naturalidade<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"naturalidade\" id=\"naturalidade\" value="+dados.naturalidade+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"morada\">Morada<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"morada\" id=\"morada\" value="+dados.morada+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"telemovel\">Telémovel<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td colspan=\"3\">";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"number\" name=\"telemovel\" id=\"telemovel\" \/ value="+dados.telemovel+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"niss\">NISS<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"number\" name=\"niss\" id=\"niss\" value="+dados.niss+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"nif\">NIF<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"number\" name=\"nif\" id=\"nif\" value="+dados.nif+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table >";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <br>";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Situação económica do utente<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                                <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"situacaoEconomica\" id=\"situacaoEconomica\" value="+dados.situacaoEconomica+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                               <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                        <br>";
strVar += "                               <table>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"trabalho\">Trabalho<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"trabalho\" id=\"trabalho\" value="+dados.trabalho+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td><td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"salario\">Salário<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"number\" name=\"salario\" id=\"salario\" value="+dados.salario+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"outros\">Outros<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"outros\" id=\"outros\" value="+dados.outros+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                         ";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                    <br>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "                <br>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td>";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Situação Familiar<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                                <tr>";
strVar += "                                 <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"possuiFamilia\" id=\"outros\" value="+dados.possuiFamilia+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                      <br>";
strVar += "                      <fieldset>";
strVar += "                      <table>";
strVar += "                          <tr>";
strVar += "                              <td>Conhecimento do agregado familiar:<\/td>";
strVar += "                          ";
strVar += "                              ";
strVar += "                          <tr>";
strVar += "                              <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"familiarProximo\">Nome familiar mais proximo<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"familiarProximo\" id=\"familiarProximo\" size=\"40\" value="+dados.familiarProximo+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"parentesco\">Grau de Parentesco<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"parentesco\" id=\"parentesco\" size=\"40\" value="+dados.parentesco+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                          <\/tr>";
strVar += "                          <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"moradaFamiliar\">Morada do Familiar<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"moradaFamiliar\" id=\"moradaFamiliar\" size=\"40\" value="+dados.moradaFamiliar+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"contactoFamiliar\">Contacto do Familiar<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <input type=\"text\" name=\"contactoFamiliar\" id=\"contactoFamiliar\" size=\"40\" value="+dados.contactoFamiliar+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                          <\/tr>";
strVar += "                      <\/tr>";
strVar += "                      <\/table>";
strVar += "                      <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                      <br>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Situação Clinica<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>                  ";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"inseridoCentroSaude\">Inserido no centro de saúde<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"inseridoCentroSaude\" id=\"inseridoCentroSaude\" value="+dados.inscritoCentroSaude+">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"qual\">Qual<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"qual\" id=\"qual\">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"medicoFamilia\">Médico de Familia<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"medicoFamilia\" id=\"medicoFamilia\">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"contacto\">Contacto<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"contacto\" id=\"contacto\">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"sns\">Nº SNS<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"sns\" id=\"sns\">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                <label for=\"grupoSanguineo\">Grupo Sanguineo<\/label>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"grupoSanguineo\" id=\"grupoSanguineo\">";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Antecedentes clinicos relevantes<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                            <textarea name=\"antecendentesClinicos\" cols=\"112\" rows=\"5\" id=\"antecendentesClinicos\"><\/textarea>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "            <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Documentos obrigatorios para entrega<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                                <td>";
strVar += "                            <li>Bilhete de Identidade ou Cartão de Cidadão<\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Cartão de Contribuinte <\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Cartão de Beneficiário da Segurança Social <\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Cartão de Utente dos Serviços de saúde ou de subsistemas <\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Boletim de vacinas e relatório médico, comprovativo da situação clínica do cliente <\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Declaração assinada pelo cliente em como autoriza a informatização dos dados pessoais para efeitos de elaboração de processo individual;<\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Boletim de saúde<\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Documentos comprovativos da sua situação económica e familiar<\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Contrato de prestação de serviços<\/li>";
strVar += "                            <li>Passaporte<\/li>";
strVar += "                                <\/td>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "             <tr>";
strVar += "                <td colspan=\"2\">";
strVar += "                    <fieldset>";
strVar += "                        <legend>Informações de Acompanhamento<\/legend>";
strVar += "                        <table>";
strVar += "                            <tr>";
strVar += "                            <textarea name=\"informacoesAcompanhamento\" cols=\"112\" rows=\"5\" id=\"informacoesAcompanhamento\"><\/textarea>";
strVar += "                            <\/tr>";
strVar += "                        <\/table>";
strVar += "                    <\/fieldset>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "            <tr> ";
strVar += "                <td>";
strVar += "                    <input  type=\"reset\" name=\"resetBtn\" id=\"limpar\" \/>";
strVar += "                    <input  type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"enviar\" \/>";
strVar += "                <\/td>";
strVar += "            <\/tr>";
strVar += "        <\/table>";
strVar += "    <\/form>";

        $('#contas').html(strVar);
      }
      }
    });
}
```

Parte do `Ajax`:

```
<?php

$ligacao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","methamorphys");
   if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
      echo "Erro na liga??o MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }


   $sql = "select * from pacientes where bi =".$_GET["bi"]."";
   $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $sql);
   $objeto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

                 $var = Array(
        'Nome' =>   $objeto["Nome"],
        'idade' =>     $objeto["idade"],
        'dataNascimento' => $objeto["dataNascimento"],
        'estadoCivil' => $objeto["estadoCivil"],
        'nacionalidade' => $objeto["nacionalidade"],
        'naturalidade' => $objeto["naturalidade"],
        'morada' => $objeto["morada"],
        'telemovel' => $objeto["telemovel"],
        'niss' => $objeto["niss"],
        'nif' => $objeto["nif"],
        'situacaoEconomica' => $objeto["situacaoEconomica"],
        'trabalho' => $objeto["trabalho"],
        'salario' => $objeto["salario"],
        'outros' => $objeto["outros"],
        'possuiFamilia' => $objeto["possuiFamilia"],
        'familiarProximo' => $objeto["familiarProximo"],
        'parentesco' => $objeto["parentesco"],
        'moradaFamiliar' => $objeto["moradaFamiliar"],
        'contactoFamiliar' => $objeto["contactoFamiliar"],
        'inscritoCentroSaude' => $objeto["inscritoCentroSaude"],
        'qual' => $objeto["qual"],
        'medicoFamilia' => $objeto["medicoFamilia"],
        'contacto' => $objeto["contacto"],
        'sns' => $objeto["sns"],
        'grupoSanguineo' => $objeto["grupoSanguineo"]
    );


   echo json_encode($var);
```

Comment: Mostre um pouco do arquivo `ajaxUtentes.php`

Comment: Ok, já adicionei

Comment: Acho que deve ser a falta de aspas nos `value` dos inputs. Exemplo: `<input type=\"text\" id=\"nome\" name=\"nome\" value='"+dados.Nome+"'>";`